# Round up cart total Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I need to round up prices on my Woocommerce cart. It rounds up to 1. For example:

If the total price of the cart is $40.85, I need the cart to show $41.00.

I tried with this command but the price discount this 0.15 and I do not know how to do it. I found this in other sites but round up the products in the catalog.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_calculated_total', 10, 2 );
function custom_calculated_total( $total, $cart ){
    return round( $total - ($total * 0.15), $cart->dp );
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.  This will round your cart total to the next dollar.  You can also use WooCommerce settings to round displayed product prices before items are added to the cart.

```
//round cart total up to nearest dollar
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_calculated_total' );
function custom_calculated_total( $total ) {
$total = round( $total, 1 );
return ceil($total);
}
```

Comment: No problem.  Glad it was helpful.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried Justin R.'s Code, with 50% success. The Total was rounded fine, but not the Subtotal. [Here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wrong-round-in-cart-and-checkout/) I found a Code that did both. It uses a different Hook "raw_woocommerce_price".
This is the Code:

```
// Round price for .99 .01 decimals
add_filter( 'raw_woocommerce_price', function ( $price ) {
$decimals = round( $price - floor( $price ), 2 );
return ( $decimals == 0.01 || $decimals == 0.99 ) ? round( $price ) : $price;
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

I am looks for some option how to round last digit in woocommerce cart and I cant find it. Maybe it will help somebody. This function works for me. Just add this code to your themes functions.php file and it will work.

```
//Rounding total price last digit in cart to zero:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_calculated_total' );
function custom_calculated_total( $total ) {
$total = round($total / 10) * 10;
return ($total);
}
```